# Problem with discord rewrite and youtube search

Tags: python, youtube, discord.py

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, term):
    search_result = yt.search(term, sMax=1, sType="video")
    print(search_result.videoId[0])
```

I have this code here and it should give me the id of the video. It worked fine like 3 months ago, but now it seems that the term only picks up the first word.

For example if I go !play Never gonna give you up, the term will be "Never".
Is there any way I can make it pick up very word.

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['p', 'pla'])
async def play(ctx, *, term):
    search_result = yt.search(term, sMax=1, sType="video")
    print(search_result.videoId[0])
```

Just add a `*` argument before `term`.